# Alternate source of repositories for ROS on UbuntuARM

Tags: beaglebone, ubuntu, armhf, beagleboneblack, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While installing ROS on BeagleBone Black running Ubuntu Trusty, the repository sources at "http://packages.namniart.com/repos/ros trusty main" are unavailable since the domain has expired, according to the web browser

Is there any alternate source for those files?

Please reply ASAP

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199589/alternate-source-of-repositories-for-ros-on-ubuntuarm/) by [AkshatAgarwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/21134/akshatagarwal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-12-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just found this: http://answers.ros.org/question/199429/could-not-resolve-packagesnamniartcom/ should be back up soon.

---

Originally posted by [Marc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18988/marc/) with karma: 46 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-18**:
It's back.